# Edge Detection vs. Contour Detection?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

What is the difference between edge detection and contour detection?

Apparently both techniques are used to detect boundaries of close shapes(whether oval shape or r rectangular shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contour is the edge closing an object.
So you can think as higher level of edge detection.

So if an edge define an object it becomes a contour.

Comment: Consider a rectangle,  it will have 4 edges(each edge across one side) and one contour made up of 4 edges? Am i right?

Comment: Yep. This is the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider the notion of **edge**, with respect to that of **contour**, in the same relation as **words** to a **sentence**. An edge is a distinctive element of an image (a color change, a border cut, a shadow, an occlusion). Here, from top to bottom: surface normal, depeth, illumination, shadow.

[image: Types of edges]

But sometimes, this  does not fully takes advantage of the whole concept of objects, which requires higher-order methods, semantics, viewpoints, etc. Look at the following 3D object, which is relatively homogeneous and isolated edges:

[image: 3D object, shadows and edges]

While edges can be detected by relatively local tools (derivatives, Laplacien, thresholding, wavelets, Gabor functions etc.), contours often require more involved and global techniques: active contours, geodesic active gradients, etc.